# What is the purpose of inferring the argument of a function as literal type?

Tags: typescript

I'm reading an [article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments#generic_inference) in which the argument of a function is inferred as literal type `{ a: 42 }` instead of just `{ a: number }`:

```
const foo = <Value extends number, T extends { a: Value }>(a: T) => a

// const foo: <{ a: 42; }> (a: { a: 42; }) => { a:42; }
foo({ a: 42 })
```

Why to do this when the function still accept any argument of type `{ a: number }`. It also says:

You may ask me why I even need to infer literal type. Because sometimes we want to validate our arguments. Imagine that you want to disallow value if it equals 1. Try to implement this validation rule.

Comment: What, specifically, is the question here?  Is it "How can `Value` be disallowed when it equals to `1`?" Or is  it "Why to infer the argument of a function as literal type?"  Please [edit] either the question or the title to make it clear what the specific question is.

Comment: (see prev comment) After that, it's a bit weird to be trying to answer the intent for someone's blog post (presumably only @captain-yosarrian from Ukraine could answer that).  I'd say that `Value` is actually just providing a hint for `T` and is almost always going to be inferred as just `number`.  So you're actually trying to disallow when `T["a"]` is `1` and not `Value`.  To that end you could maybe do it [this way](https://tsplay.dev/w1aL8w). Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Now that you've edited the question I'm not sure how anyone who didn't write the blog could answer it authoritatively.  So all you'll get here is various opinions about why one might want to do such a thing.  [Literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) have uses, so sometimes people will have use cases where they want such types inferred.  What else can be said here that isn't opinion?

Comment: if the problem is just a lack of imagination for potential use cases, imagine you need that literal type to cook a more useful return type: maybe you need to build a tuple of exactly N elements for example, and maybe the length of that tuple is bounded, so you want to check that the argument is between 1 and 6 or whatever. A concrete example of that (even though it's not deeply nested in an object) is the `FlatArray` type which needs a `Depth` parameter

Comment: If I can give a piece of advice: having readonly parameters is not a bad thing at all. The [const modifier on type parameters](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/51865) should replace most of this forced type narrowing use cases.

Comment: @jcalz I found it interesting the way generics are used to infer deeply but I don't know of its practical usage, in the `foo` function of the example; `<T extends { a: number }>` is enough to me,  instead of `<Value extends number, T extends { a: Value }>`. Me as new to TS, I'm being happy if you don't know either.

Comment: This is a dummy function, of course there is no obvious use for a narrower type

Answer (score 0):

The most commonly used literal inferring pattern is infering `K extends keyof Something` so you may determine which overload (with accordinate `Something[K]` value type for other arguments or returns) you need

```
interface Document {
    /** Returns the first element that is a descendant of node that matches selectors. */
    querySelector<K extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap>(selectors: K): HTMLElementTagNameMap[K] | null;
}
```